# Python & Tweepy - How to compare and change times.

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, tweepy

I am trying to create a number of constraints for some other code based on twitter handle sets.

I am having issues with the following code because:

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to str
```

It seems that even though I have changed Last_Post to a datetime object initially, when i compare it to datetime.datetime.today() it is converting to string. Yes, I have checked the to ensure that Last_post is converting properly. Im not really sure what is going on. Help?

```
for handle in handles:
    try:
        user = api.get_user(handle)
        #print json.dumps(user, indent = 4)
        verified = user["verified"]
        name = user['name']
        language = user['lang']
        follower_count = user['followers_count']
        try:
            last_post = user['status']['created_at']
            last_post = datetime.strptime(last_post, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
        except: 
            last_post = "User has not posted ever"
        location = user['location']

        location_ch = location_check(location)

        if location_ch is not "United States":
            location_output.append(False)
        else:
            location_output.append(True)

        new_sum.append(follower_count)

        if language is not "en":
            lang_output.append(False)
        else:
            lang_output.append(True)

        if datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30) > last_post:
            recency.append(False)
        else:
            recency.append(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to convert the twitter date to a timestamp:

```
import time

ts = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(tweet['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'))
```